# No response from curl operation but success in postman

Tags: php, curl, yii2

The below one i tested with postman its returning the response but when i check in the PHP its not returning any response.please help me.

**cURL file creation:**

```
$curl_file = curl_file_create(\Yii::$app->basePath.'/web/uploads/'.$uploadedFile->name,'pbix',$uploadedFile->baseName);
            $params = ['file' => $curl_file];
```

**cURL Process:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://***.***.**.***/v1.0/collections/**/workspaces/**/***?datasetDisplayName=new test",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: key",
          ),
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;
        }
```

Comment: I recommend you to remove your key. Your key should be private, not posted here on SO.

Comment: @Twinfriends i removed it

Comment: What's the output of the Curl? An error? A blank string?

Comment: no error ...just empty response

Comment: if it shows some error i could check from that but not

Comment: What's HTTP code have your answer? 200?

Comment: i couldn't get you @Bartosz Kowalczyk

Comment: Tell what you will receive from that line: 

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($response, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: curl_getinfo() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Comment: above one im getting

Comment: Sorry for mistake. no $response but $curl. $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
second thing are you sure that answer is not chunked? Or zipped?

Comment: ya im getting 400

Comment: or better give me result for that (please, change variable to your, it is snip code from my code):

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// ...

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Then, after your curl_exec call:
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

Comment: So you receive answer. This is REST API probably. So it's can use a HTTP code for communication. In this situation you receive 400 code.
Usually it is mean "Bad Request"
So you need to check your request up to documentation. Youe have something wrong in your URL or $params.

Comment: ok but the problem is its working in postman and im getting the response

Comment: Of course you got response. Response returned you 400 - Bad Request. Their API returned empty body (so it look like "blank response". Header in your answer saying -  "bad request". Try to encode your special char such as for instance space. (space to %20) in URL. Post should be ok.

Comment: thanks for your time @Bartosz Kowalczyk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is space in the parameter.The `space` should be replaced by `%20`. you need to do like below:

```
$url="https://***.***.**.***/v1.0/collections/**/workspaces/3b09eff6-69ae-4932-9419-14eeb69a9dbd/***?datasetDisplayName=new test";
$curl_url=str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
```

or you have to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).This is used when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL.

```
$curl_url="https://***.***.**.***/v1.0/collections/**/workspaces/3b09eff6-69ae-4932-9419-14eeb69a9dbd/***?datasetDisplayName=urlencode(new test)";
```

Then

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $curl_url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: key",
            ),
        ));
```